# Black screen when executing test app on Tizen Emulator

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app

I'm starting to work with Tizen and I'm following its tutorials. When I test my apps, they only get with a black screen when I open them on the emulator, and I don't know why is that.

Would someone know what can cause this, and how to solve it?
I'm using Windows 7 64bits, I've installed the Intel Haxm and enabled the virtualization. The emulator seems to work fine, but, I still get this problem with my apps.

Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Turn the GPU of the emulator off . In some machines GPU is not supported.
GPU option is available in the emulator manager.

Comment: Good to hear... You can accept this as answer so that it can be helpful to others having the same problem..

Comment: If this does not solve the issue, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Could be that your intel haxm is not working, 
causing your emulator to be very (very) slow.

Go to : 
System -> Adjust the appearance and performance of Windows -> 
 DEP (DATA EXECUTION PREVENTION) -> check the second option.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, but i solve it disabling "CPU VT" on HW Support when you create a new emulator.

Screenshot:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have similar issue. In my case the root cause was incorrect work of CPU virtualization. 
My Lenovo laptop had Intel Core i7 on board which supports virtualization. But it worked incorrectly. To fix the issue I did the following steps:

1. Disabled virtualization in BIOS and restarted Windows.
2. Enabled virtualization in BIOS.
3. Created new Emulator.

Hope this will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue in TizenStudio 3.6
In emulator manager / Hw support, I disabled CPU-VT, and it was working.